# Facebook API: search for people and contact them?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a large list of our customers that we'd like our FB app to find, contact, invite, etc. I'm not sure what the allowed policies are for such things, and what all the API allows. I know such apps could generate incredible amount of spam.

- Can my app search for random people and get info about them?
- Can my app invite such people to do something like become a friend, like the app, use the app, etc.?
- Can my app place a targeted ad for certain demographics I discover?

ps: Maybe you can just point me to the link where I can check this out myself, Googling wasn't that helpful.

Comment: No, not any of the things you list is possible or allowed

Comment: @WizKid Maybe target ads by postal code and gender? I know it's broad but customers would probably self-recognize and approve the app for more interaction later.

Comment: Search for random people and have users auth the app is two different things

Comment: Well the goal is the same, use the existing database of customers to get them to auth the app, programmatically by API, those who'd like to auth the app.

Comment: You can't auth the app for them. You will have to send them to the Facebook login and ask for permissions and they will have to choose if they want to give those permissions to you